# How to print CGRect in lldb (reverse engineering)

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, lldb

Trying to get rectange. Withing AppKit I just use NSRect and it works like a charm. On iOS I fail:

```
(lldb) e @import UIKit
(lldb) e @import CoreGraphics
(lldb) e @import Foundation
(lldb) po (CGRect)$rax
error: 'CGRect' is an incomplete type
forward declaration of 'CGRect'
```

Similar problem I have with this call (rectangle issues)

```
(lldb) po [$rdi bounds]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

[image: lldb]

Comment: xcode 9.1 beta with restart, xcode 8 can at least successfully do  po (CGRect)[$rax bounds]
(origin = (x = 30, y = 72.799999999999997), size = (width = 36, height = 43))